# Why will my Pixel 3a XL no longer take screenshots?

Tags: screenshots

I have a Pixel 3a XL phone running Android 11.

Until recently I was able to take screenshots by holding down the power button and then selecting screenshot from the menu.

However, over the past week or two, something -- I don't know what -- has changed and when I hold down the power button, I get a different menu as shown below.

I don't remember exactly when this started, nor do I know how to see a list of apps on my phone sorted in order of most recently installed.

So how can I get my screen-shot functionality back??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's gone and you can't just "get it back"...

A quick Google search would have answered this from multiple sources including Google itself, but I will to answer it. They (Google) removed that screenshot method from Android 11 and replaced it with a screenshot tool in the task switching screen using "swipe up and hold" gesture. This does require you to use Gesture Navigation though. However the long time Android standard for screenshots of POWER+VOL DN still works and has since about Android 2.1.

Google asked about this: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/72969834?hl=en

How the new gesture system works: https://www.androidcentral.com/how-take-screenshots-and-select-text-multitasking-pane-android-11

Again, you must be using Gesture Navigation for the later method to work, otherwise you have to use the old POWER+VOL DN method. This may change in the future or not, it is a very polarizing subject among Android users, it's about a 50/50 split of people who want the old way and people who prefer the new way.

Comment: Thank u! Gesture Navigation doesn't bring up that option for me. 
However the Power + Volume Down button did work and I like it a lot.